# How do I check if a string is NOT a floating number?

Tags: javascript

```
var num = "10.00";
if(!parseFloat(num)>=0)
{
    alert("NaN");
}
else
{
    alert("Number");
}
```

I want to check if a value is not a float number, but the above code always returns `NaN`, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!parseFloat(num)` is `false` so you are comparing `false >= 0`

You could do this:

```
if(! (parseFloat(num)>=0))
```

But it would be more readable to do this:

```
if(parseFloat(num) < 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

`parseFloat` returns either a float or `NaN`, but you are applying the Boolean NOT operator `!` to it and then comparing it to another floating point.

You probably want something more like:

```
var num = "10.0";
var notANumber = isNaN(parseFloat(num));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `!` has a higher precedence than `>=`, so your code does

`!parseFloat(num)` which is `false`

Then

`>= 0`, `false` is coerced into `0`, and `0 >= 0` is true, thus the `alert("NaN")`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 0):

```
function isFloat(value) {
  if(!val || (typeof val != "string" || val.constructor != String)) {
  return(false);
  }
  var isNumber = !isNaN(new Number(val));
     if(isNumber) {
        if(val.indexOf('.') != -1) {
           return(true);
        } else {
           return(false);
        }
     } else {
  return(false);
 }
}
```

[ref](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/115310/float-value-checking)